# Ramda 'when' not producing expected result

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm expecting arrayTester to look at each array within the array and if both elements are empty strings for them to be removed from the array. Instead I am getting back the original array.

Expected result = [[], ['string', '']]

Actual result = [['',''], ['string', '']]

Any ideas?

```
let data = [['',''], ['string', '']]
const emptyString = R.equals('')
const removeEmptyElementsFunc = R.reject(R.isEmpty)
const arrayTester = (data) => {
 R.forEach(
        R.when(
          R.all(emptyString),
          R.map(removeEmptyElementsFunc)
        )(data))
        return data
      }

arrayTester(data)
```

Comment: You don't want to use `forEach`.

Comment: @Bergi same result when removing forEach.

Comment: I mean you would want to `map` instead. The `data` is not changed by anything, you create new values but throw them away.

Comment: Please don't use shortened URLs. The only reason to use them is when you are limited as to the number of characters you can post. That is not significantly the case on Stack Overflow questions and answers. Using a shortened URL makes the link appear nefarious, because they are often used to hide malware links, tracking links (such as the one you used), or to hide spam, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to map an array of empty strings to an empty array, the only thing you need to do is to make sure that it is indeed only made of empty strings. *(The "transformation" is rather easy: just return an empty array.)*

`all(isEmpty)` will return `true` if an array is made of empty stuff. `always([])` will always return an empty array.

```js
const arrayTester = map(when(all(isEmpty), always([])));

console.log(

  arrayTester([['', ''], ['a', 'b', '']]),
  arrayTester([['', '', ''], ['a', 'b', '']]),
  arrayTester([['', 'x', ''], ['a', 'b', '']])
  
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {map, when, all, isEmpty, always} = R;</script>
```

Comment: Well I won't know exactly how many empty strings will be in each array. Hence my need to look at each array and see if the whole thing is made of empty strings. I should have made that more clear in my question.

Comment: No worries I'll update accordingly. What if an array is made of empty strings except one, e.g. `['', '', 'a', '']`. Do you need to keep the array intact or filter out the empty strings?

Comment: Keep the array intact